# What is the equivalent of Oracle's ANYINTERACT+TOUCH spatial operator for Vividsolution's Geometry class?

Tags: java, oracle, gis, oracle-spatial, jts

I'm re-writing an old Oracle PL/SQL procedure in Java and one query has the following where clause:

```
WHERE SDO_RELATE(shape, v_retrv_geo,'MASK=ANYINTERACT+TOUCH') = 'TRUE'
```

`shape` and `v_retrv_geo` are both of type `SDO_GEOMETRY`. Specifically `shape` is an area defined by boundaries and `v_retrv_geo` is a point created from a lat/lon pair.

[Oracle's docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_intro.htm#SPATL460) say `ANYINTERACT` means the objects are non-disjoint (with disjoint being defined as the boundaries and interiors do not intersect) and `TOUCH` means the boundaries intersect but the interiors do not intersect. I *think* the `+TOUCH` part of the mask is redundant, but the existing query returns correct results according to the business folks.

My version of the same query using Java's streams looks like:

```
.filter(area -> area.getShape().intersects(p) || area.getShape().touches(p))
```

where both `p` and the results of `area.getShape()` are `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry`. `p` is the point that represents `v_retrv_geo` and `area.getShape()` is the `Geometry` object created from the `shape` column used in the old query.

[Vividsolution's docs](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.11/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry.java) say `intersects` means the two geometries have at least one point in common and `touches` means the geometries have at least one point in common, but their interiors do not intersect.

For some points, the Java version returns more areas than the old PL/SQL version when both are consuming data from the same tables.

Comment: "For some points, the Java version returns more areas than the old PL/SQL version when both are consuming data from the same tables." what do the situations that are returnedby Vividsolution and but by Oracle have in common? Have you looked at the geometries, drawn them in an image? What do your business people say about these cases, should they be included or excluded?

Comment: Oracle's ANYINTERACT definitely includes TOUCH, so yes, TOUCH is redundant. The equivalent for JTS should be .intersects. What happens when you use that alone ? You should get the same results as in Oracle.